# AWS Redshift - Extract tables watermark

Tags: amazon-redshift, database-administration

How is possible to get table watermarks on AWS Redshift? I've searched in internet but I didn't find any command to extract it.

Comment: What is a "table watermark"? What do you wish to accomplish with it? (That is, _why_ are you wanting this capability?)

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of  table watermarks for AWS Redshift.